# capturing speaker output using javascript

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, getusermedia

is it possible to capture speaker output while playing audio on the laptop?

I have explored the webAudio and p5js API but did not get any clue. I have also gone through the getUserMedia api which only works to record the microphone audio (input audio to the device).

Comment: Where do you want to get the speaker output from? In Web audio api you always determine the speaker output I think you cannot access the speaker itself and get the output in gerneral like from other sources. Sou you can't hear what the user hears from other programs. That would big a pretty big security leak as well. If you would describe your question further what you want to do perhaps we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't be done using javascript that runs in a tab in your browser. You would have to use software that runs on your OS to make this happen.